# Combining a user-defined float inside a shadowbox

Tags: floats, listings

Is it possible to combine the "program" part in a shadowbox?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{float}

\floatstyle{ruled}
\newfloat{program}{thp}{lop}
\floatname{program}{Program}

\begin{document}

\begin{program} ## FROM HERE
  \begin{lstlinsting}[basicstyle={\footnotesize},language=Java,showstringspaces=false,tabsize=4]

class HelloWorldApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Display the string
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
  }
}
\end{lstlisting}
  \caption{The Hello World! program in Java.}
\end{program} ## TO HERE

\end{document}
```

The example was slightly modified from the one at the bottom of [link text](http://andy-roberts.net/misc/latex/latextutorial6.html). Here is an image of what I want to the shadowbox to look like. The image is borrowed from the above page.

[image]

Comment: not sure if this will work exactly how you want it, but it looks pretty close: shadethm package: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/shadethm/

Answer (score 2):

Try one of the shadowed styles from the [`floatrow`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/floatrow/) package.  Look at table 1 of the manual to see if one of them suits you.